# Looping animated ScrollView in Android pauses between repeats

Tags: android, repeat, objectanimator

I'm implementing a slot machine in Android. The reels are ScrollViews with LinearLayouts as children, and the individual tiles as ImageViews vertically oriented inside the LinearLayout.  I'm using an ObjectAnimator to scroll to the end of the ScrollView, using ValueAnimator.RESTART and ValueAnimator.INFINITE. The reel scrolling is nice and smooth, however when it comes time to repeat, it pauses for a second, which ruins the effect.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
  public void spinReel(SlotReel reel) {
        final int reelSize = this.context.getPixelsInDPs(64);
        final SlotMachineView me = this;
        final SlotReel myReel = reel;
        ImageView[] tiles = reel.getTiles();
        int delta = tiles.length - reel.currentTileNumber();
        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(reel, "scrollY", tiles.length * reelSize );
        animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        animator.setDuration(delta * 75);
        animator.setStartDelay(0);
        animator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
        animator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
                myReel.scrollTo(0, reelSize * 3);

            }
        });
        animator.start();

    }
```

Note that the jerkiness occurs whether or not I put the scrollTo in the Repeat callback.

Example video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dcezeKhAlA&list=UUgAEQ3EVjDEG2Ttdp212ZLQ):

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
```

look here 
[Android ValueAnimator pauses during repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19938394/android-valueanimator-pauses-during-repeat)

Comment: In addition to providing an answer, please explain why your answer will help the OP's question.